# I had a problem when installing Atom in Fedora. My installation method was like this

Tags: fedora

how instal atom in fedora

how instal atom in fedora for use python and django
please help me

Enable snaps on Fedora and install atom
Snaps are applications packaged with all their dependencies to run on all popular Linux distributions from a single build. They update automatically and roll back gracefully.

Snaps are discoverable and installable from the Snap Store, an app store with an audience of millions.
Enable snapd

Snap can be installed on Fedora from the command line:

sudo dnf install snapd

Either log out and back in again, or restart your system, to ensure snap’s paths are updated correctly.

To enable classic snap support, enter the following to create a symbolic link between /var/lib/snapd/snap and /snap:

sudo ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap

Install atom

To install atom, simply use the following command:

sudo snap install atom --classic